# Angular.js : Accessing url parameters before route has changed

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying a new architecture for angular authentication and have run into a problem with routes with wildcard parameters...

In my route config I set

```
      .when('/:username', {
            templateUrl: '/views/client/login.html',
            controller: 'ClientLoginCtrl'
        })

       .when('/:username/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: '/views/client/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'ClientDashboardCtrl',
            accessLevel: ACCESS_LEVELS.client
        })
```

So that every user has their own folder in the url. And the user dashboard route is protected.

I set a constant defining levels and the route to go to if not authenticated. As you can see below I try to set a `/:username` parameter as I want to return them to the user login page if they try to go to a deeper page and not logged in...

```
.constant('ACCESS_LEVELS', {
    client: {
        level: 1,
        denied: '/:username'
    },
    admin: {
        level: 2,
        denied: '/admin'
    }
})
```

Then I test in a $routeChangeStart event if they are authenticated.. if not.. i want to return the user to the denied route defined in the constant above...

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location, Auth){

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, next){
            if(!Auth.isAuthorised(next.$$route.accessLevel.level))
            {
                   $location.path(next.$$route.accessLevel.denied);
            }
    });
```

This was all working great until I introduced the `:username` parameter in the url. $routeParams aren't set until after the route has changed so aren't available in the $routeChangeStart event. If I go to /sample-user/dashboard and aren't logged in, the URL changes to /:username... not /sample-user which is want I want.

Can anyone think of a simple way to get around this problem?

Comment: Is the params set when you listen to `$routeChangeSuccess`?

Comment: @ivarni I had thought of that but was trying to avoid it as it doesn't feel right... but maybe it's the only way! Thanks!